# Is the space of PDFs a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions

Prove or disprove:  $Q = \{f \in R \to R_{+}: ||f|| = 1, f(\lambda) \geq 0\}$ is a vector space with addition, scalar multiplication and zero defined as 
$$f + g = \int_R f(u)g(\lambda - u)du$$
$$cf = F^{-1}(F(f)^c)$$
$$0 = \delta(\lambda)$$
$F$ denotes the fourier transform, $\delta(\lambda)$ dirac delta.